# java.util.zip.ZipException ZIP_Read: error reading zip file

Tags: java, jar, zip, backend, zipexception

How can I get:

java.util.zip.ZipException ZIP_Read: error reading zip file?

I've tried with different corrupted zips, corrupted jars, but no luck so far. Any idea?

Comment: A bad header? Try overwriting the first four bytes of a zip file with random values

Comment: do you have some code which you can share?

Comment: Good. Let me know!

Comment: g00se many thanks but still no luck...

Comment: @g00se That'll just give you an error about corrupt local header (the real "header" of a zip file is at the end - a fact I didn't know before GIFAR). This error sounds like a problem with the underlying read - so truncation, remote storage failure or perhaps deletion of the file may do the trick.

Comment: Done ;) FYI: Finally I got this exception on opening an empty ZIP file. Thanks, Guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void play() {
    try {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("./data/demo.zip");
        ZipArchiveEntry zipArchiveEntry;
        Enumeration<ZipArchiveEntry> entries = zipFile.getEntries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            zipArchiveEntry = entries.nextElement();
            long size = zipArchiveEntry.getSize();
        // more code
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).